# Can a BLE(v4.2) device which is in slave role have multiple masters?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I wanted to know if the Link layer of the LE device is in slave role can have multiple masters. I know that master can have multiple slaves but can a slave have multiple masters ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
If one slave device have multiple masters to connect with it, it need multiple GAP/GATT instances, don't have this kind of application example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is allowed since Bluetooth 4.1 but was not allowed in Bluetooth 4.0.

From the specification:

> The Link Layer in the Connection State operating in the Slave Role may have multiple connections.